# HTML - Make divs inside a div have full height

Tags: html, css

I use the above code in an effort to create a div with 3 smaller divs in it. Code works good but there is a blank space on the bottom... How can I extend the height of each div so they take equally the full height of the outer div (without having to set `height: ...` for each one of them)?
Thanks

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    .div1 {
     border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .div2 {
     border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .div3 {
     border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .div4 {
     border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="div1">
     <div class="div2">Just</div>
        <div class="div3">A</div>
        <div class="div4">Test</div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you might think that the easiest way would be to set all of the inner div's to `height: 33.33%;`, but the borders of the inner div's provide difficulty, as shown in the example below:

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
.div1 > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: calc(33% - 2px);
}
.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: gray;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Just</div>
  <div class="div3">A</div>
  <div class="div4">Test</div>
</div>
```

To fix this, you could set the div's height to `height: calc(33.33% - 2px);`

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
.div1 > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: calc(33.33% - 2px);
}
.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: gray;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Just</div>
  <div class="div3">A</div>
  <div class="div4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Or you could use `outline` instead of `border` ie change

```
  border: 1px solid red;
```

to

```
  outline: 1px solid red;
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
.div1 > div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 33.33%;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: gray;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Just</div>
  <div class="div3">A</div>
  <div class="div4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Another way would be to set the parent to `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` and set the inner div's to `flex: 1;` and that will also work.

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.div1 > div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: gray;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Just</div>
  <div class="div3">A</div>
  <div class="div4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 100px;` line from the `.div1` section or use following rule to set height of inner divs:

```
.div1 > div {
    height: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `height: 33.33%;` on inner div. Check updated snippet below.

```css
*,*:after,*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.div1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}
.div2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 33.33%;
}
.div3 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 33.33%;
}
.div4 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">Just</div>
    <div class="div3">A</div>
    <div class="div4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the parent `div` height to `100%`

```
.div1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This makes the parent div smaller, rather than making the inner div's bigger, which is what the OP asked for.